# How do I receive ipv6 multicast packets addressed to "ff01::1"?

Tags: linux, ipv6, multicast, legacy

[image: A sample of the packets reaching the NIC]

Hello. In my job I have to interface with a buggy multicasting implementation that sends to my machines packets addressed to ff01::1. I know this does not make sense, since the scope "01" in the address is interface-local. But the legacy system does this anyway, and that is not something I can change. I have to find a way to receive these datagrams.

The old systems seem to ignore the multicast scope, and send the packets through the network anyway, but a more modern stack (Ubuntu 16.04) is not allowing me to receive any of these packets through a socket, even though they are visible using packet capture (Wireskark).

My question is, is there a way to received these multicast packets addressed to ff01::1 on a modern Linux stack, using sockets?

**(edit:)** corrected from "link-local" to "interface-local"

Comment: Those packets sent to that multicast address are _not_ link-local, they are _interface_-local, and they should not leave the sending host. See [RFC 4291](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.7): "_Interface-Local scope spans only a single interface on a node and is useful only for loopback transmission of multicast._"

Comment: Right, I corrected that piece of information. It is interface-local, not link-local. But that is the problem, really. The legacy systems are merrily throwing those packages at the router with absolutely no concern for my job security. The router sends everyone the packets anyway, and the legacy systems do not care about the multicast scope. But my new system seems to care, and that sucks, because I need to receive these.

Comment: Routers do not route multicast packets unless multicast routing is enabled, and even then, they do not route interface-local packets. The problem lies with the multicast source application, and the broken application needs to be fixed. You don't change IP to work with your application, you change the application to work with IP.

Comment: Since I can't touch any of the legacy stuff, I decided to create a helper application based on libpcap, a tunnel of sorts, to deal with the brokenness. At least then the interoperability ugliness is isolated to a single point. Thank you so much for the advice!

Comment: I don't think this is even a "legacy" problem because even by [RFC 1884, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1884) from December 1995, that would not be a valid multicast group to used to send packets outside the host. The application programmer apparently had a design flaw or a bug that created the situation.

Comment: Agreed. The more I found out about the situation the weirder it got. It is a bug that was abused and now there is no sound solution I can think of, besides capturing and throwing around raw Ethernet frames. Not even RAW sockets would let me receive the stuff.